# Navigation Drawer update causing crash (App compact v7)

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-support-library

I am getting the following log on Navigation Drawer:

```
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field DrawerArrowToggle of type [I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable' appears in /data/app/com.exa-1/base.apk)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.support.v7.app.DrawerArrowDrawable.<init>(DrawerArrowDrawable.java:64)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle$DrawerArrowDrawableToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:469)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:222)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.<init>(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:150)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at com.exa.MainActivity$2.<init>(MainActivity.java:199)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at com.exa.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:201)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
11-27 09:32:11.811: E/AndroidRuntime(2149):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I am trying to update my drawer to the one in play store with the arrow, here are my imports:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
```

The log corresponds to the following lines in my code:

```
mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.string.app_name, // 
                R.string.app_name // <~~~~ THIS LINE, Culprit identified!
) {

            public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
                if(slideOffset > .55 && !drawerOpen){
                    onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                    drawerOpen = true;
                } else if(slideOffset < .45 && drawerOpen) {
                    onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                    drawerOpen = false;
                }
            } 





            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
```

I have added the support library v7 by placing it in my libs folder and adding to build path, it is ticked in the Order and Export, but I can see android.support.v7.appcompact in my gen folder with its R.java.

I have also added the appcompact_v7 as a reference project. What do I miss here?

Answer (score 3):

I don't see any problem with the code.

Try to import v7 appcompat with resources for your project instead of adding directly appcompat library .jar file to libs folder.

Here is the link for importing appcompat with resources 
https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 1):

Add the v7 appcompat project as library, link it in your main project and make sure you compile both against Android 5.0.
Refer to Pallavi's link for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit late, but for me the problem was with **including the support library** as a library project in my build path. In addition to creating a library project around the jar files, you also need to manage the dilemma of having several versions/"revisions" of support library's jar files, which I will explain.

Regarding the line you have marked, the R class is generated at build time, so if your build fails (for any reason), there would not be any R class, that's why you get an error where you are trying to access the R class.

If you use Intellij Idea (or Android Studio, as it is sort of a subset of Intellij), make sure to add **one and only one 'revision'** (e.g. 19.0 or 20.0 or 21.0) of the support library jar files (e.g. android-support-v4 or android-support-appcompat-v7) as a **"project" library** and then add that "library" as a **dependency in each "module"** that uses the support library (project structure > modules). Add the same jars you included in your wrapper support library project, as the *project-level* libraries, and do not forget to add these "libraries" as dependency to your MAIN module as well as all other modules (eclipse projects) that use the support library.

If you are using some other libraries/dependencies, chances are that they are using the support library's android-support-v4 and/or android-support-appcompat-v7, and this can cause version conflict (and the `multi dex` error). So make sure to remove their dependency on the mentioned jar file at the module level, and add your project-level library to those modules.

Please note that there is a difference between the **revision** of support library jar files and the **version** number that is part of their name. Revisions refer to Android platform's API level (Android version) for which you have downloaded the support library (using the SDK manager) and (for which) the jar has been updated to offer new features in that specific API level too. The version included in the names of jars, is the “minimum” SDK required by that specific jar.

**Pick a revision that is compatible with all of the libraries you are using**. The newer revisions of support library are not necessarily backward compatible, some stuff might have been deleted in newer revisions.

If you come from Eclipse, in Intellij Idea's terminology, a "module" is a library project (a project with resources (like graphics) in addition to code, just like the support library or a chart drawing library for example). In addition to library projects, a regular Eclipse project is also considered a “module” and the “project" is considered a set of (related) modules (one main module, the rest as library modules).

If you have built your project in another IDE, **make sure to "rebuild" your project (in Intellij Idea) or "clean" (in Eclpise)** before running your app. Unfortunately Eclipse and Intellij Idea/Android Studio are not compatible and compiled files created by one cannot be read by the other.

Comment: For me the problem was an older google play services lib - I updated that and all worked well :) Thank you matey!